# Bootable Version on USB drive

Tags: installation, usb

I downloaded the files through this website onto my flashdrive and am wondering how to boot it up?

Comment: What website? and What have you downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Just copying the files onto the flash drive can’t help booting. You need to make a **bootable USB** with special applications.

First download the ISO file from the [Ubuntu site](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop), then create a bootable drive:

How to create a bootable USB stick on **Windows**?

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

How to create a bootable USB stick on **Ubuntu**?

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu